# Spark-shell path not specified exception

Tags: scala, apache-spark, streaming, apache-kafka

I am using spark shell from 2.1 on linux.

`./bin/spark-shell --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.1.0`

Spark shell starts well without any problem.

`val ds1 = spark.readStream.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "xx.xx.xxx.xxx:9092,xx.xx.xxx.xxx:9092").option("subscribe", "MickyMouse").load()`

I get the following exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'path' is not specified
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$9.apply(DataSource.scala:205)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$9.apply(DataSource.scala:205)
  at scala.collection.MapLike$class.getOrElse(MapLike.scala:128)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.CaseInsensitiveMap.getOrElse(CaseInsensitiveMap.scala:23)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.sourceSchema(DataSource.scala:204)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.sourceInfo$lzycompute(DataSource.scala:87)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.sourceInfo(DataSource.scala:87)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamingRelation$.apply(StreamingRelation.scala:30)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.load(DataStreamReader.scala:124)

The kafka server is up and running.
```

Any Idea how I can successfully read from kafka source.

Answer (score 0):

You forget to call the `format` method. The default format is `parquet`. That's why it's looking for a path. Changing your codes to `spark.readStream.format("kafka").option...` should fix this issue.

Comment: I did try that before  :  val ds1 = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "xx.xx.xxx.xxx:9092,xx.xx.xxx.xxx:9092").option("subscribe", "MickyMouse").load()  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: kafka. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html, I tried looking in the web page and did not know how the problem can be solved.  Thanks for your response.  Appreciate it

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kafka.DefaultSource
  at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.findClass(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:62)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)

Comment: You need to add Structured Streaming Kafka connector to your classpath. See http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#deploying Make sure change the parameter to match your Scala version.

Comment: I think the problems I had were due to company firewall preventing access to maven repository.  I downloaded the following jars and copied them to jars folder where all the spark jars are kept.     The jars are :   spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.0.0.jar spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-assembly_2.11-2.1.0.jar spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.1.0.jar spark-sql_2.11-2.1.0.jar kafka-clients-0.10.2.1.jar kafka_2.11-0.10.2.1.jar.  This helped to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should resolve the issue:

```
$spark2-shell --jars /tmp/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.3.0.jar

Scala>val df = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "node01:9093,node02:9093,node03:9093").option("subscribe", "testTopic").load()

df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [key: binary, value: binary ... 5 more fields]
```

I know it's too late to respond but might help some folks who get similar issue.